# When copying a file from a S3 bucket using Mule can you rename the file?

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, mule, anypoint-studio

I want to process a CSV file from a S3 bucket and when processing is complete I want to copy the object to a processed folder and then delete the original.

When I use the AWS S3 connector I see there is an operation called copy object and just wanted to know if there was a way I could rename the file when using this operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can rename when using the Amazon connector in Mule. In the below image the file is renamed to it's original filename using the key. You could use this to rename to your desired filename using MEL if required

[image: Amazon Connector Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the operation as requested. Please refer the S3 bucket documentation on Copying object

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectsExamples.html

Mule S3 connector Sample

```
<s3:copy-object config-ref="Amazon-aws-Config" sourceBucketName="mybucket" sourceKey="source.csv" destinationKey="destination.csv" doc:name="Amazon S3"/>
```

Hope this helps!